# Spawn subprocess in R

Tags: r, linux, monetdb

I'm trying to spawn a sub-process in R using the subprocess library, as presented in [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/subprocess/vignettes/intro.html) tutorial. The Problem is that the program I'm trying to launch requires an additional command after the executable.

Example:

I would launch the command from the shell like this:

```
monetdbd create mydb
```

where 'create' is the additional command and 'mydb' a parameter.

I tried giving 'create mydb' as parameters in R like this:

```
handle <- spawn_process('/usr/local/bin/monetdb', c('create mydb'))
```

However from the output I got with

```
process_read(handle, PIPE_STDOUT, timeout = 3000)
```

I conclude that the parameters don't work as I'm getting the info message from monetdb on how to call it, just as if I call only 'monetdb' without the create command from the shell:

```
Usage: monetdb [options] command [command-options-and-arguments]
```

The second thing I tried is to include the create command into the path, but this leads to a "No such file and directory" error.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MonetDB is the daemon process for MonetDB and has little to do with the (now old) version of MonetDBlite used in R. The latter one is decommissioned from CRAN and a newer version of MonetDBlite is expected to arrive early next year.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the package you’re using, and going purely by [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/subprocess/versions/0.8.3/topics/spawn_process), I think you need to separate the command line arguments you pass to the functions:

```
handle <- spawn_process('/usr/local/bin/monetdb', c('create',  'mydb'))
```

This also follows the “conventional” API of `spawn`/`fork`/`exec` functions.

In addition, using `c(…)` is (almost) only necessary when creating a vector of *multiple* elements. In your code (and in the tutorial) it’s *unnecessary* around a single character string.

Furthermore, contrary to what the tutorial claims, this functionality is actually already built into R via the `system2` and `pipe` functions (although I don’t doubt that the subprocess package is more feature-complete, and likely easier to use).

But if your ultimate goal is to use MonetDB in R then you’re probably better advised following the other answer, and using dedicated MonetDB R bindings rather than interacting with the daemon binary via subprocess communication.